# How to open chrome in incognito tab

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb, google-chrome-app, appium

I have a scenario open a web link in incognito tab in chrome browser. I am using adb command to open chrome and navigate to specific URL i.e `adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d weburl` .

Is there any way to open link directly in incognito mode through adb?

Comment: Please note: the [[tag:google-chrome-app]] tag is not for Chrome itself.

Comment: Looking at the [ADB command list](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) and [ADB Shell Commands](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html#shellcommands), there isn't any command that enables you to open a weburl in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any way using `adb` commands. But using `ChromeOptions` it is possible if we add "`--incognito`" argument.

Comment: Can you please share more details on how this works?

Answer (score 2):

Try this! it will work.

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.incognito.IncognitoTabLauncher
```

Comment: is any way open with url?

Answer (score -1):

You can launch chrome in incognito mode with the `-incognito` flag. I am not sure if this will work through ADB, however.

Comment: Android apps are not launched from scratch like those in other operating systems, instead a request is sent to a system daemon which forks off a copy of itself and loads the app code as a library.  Because there is no invocation, there is no (app-specific) command line to pass this argument on.