# opening chrome in incognito mode and visit a URL in an Android device

Tags: android, browser, adb, appium, incognito-mode

I want to open a browser in incognito mode in a real Android device and then visit a URL. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198003/how-to-open-chrome-in-incognito-tab) which asks how to do it with ADB and it looks like it is not supported. 
The other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568714/open-chrome-in-incognito-mode-on-real-android-device-using-appium) asks how to do the same thing with Appium, and again people said that it is not possible. 
I couldn't find any other way to do it, does it mean that we cannot open a browser in incognito mode in a real Android device programmatically? That's very unfortunate!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you just want a browser window with no history, open up your own `WebView` and clear out the history/cache after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Chrome in incognito mode on real Android Device using Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568714/open-chrome-in-incognito-mode-on-real-android-device-using-appium)

Comment: already asked the same question in stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568714/open-chrome-in-incognito-mode-on-real-android-device-using-appium?noredirect=1&lq=1